# Javascript .replace() functioning differently in console vs. live

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to do some basic string manipulation on a text variable in Javascript. I have a few lines of code that look like this:

```
var someVar = 'first+last@domain.com';
var cleanVar = someVar.replace('@','_').replace('+','_');
```

When I run this code in Chrome's Javascript console, the value of `cleanVar` is `first_last_domain.com`... which is as intended. When this code runs on the live page in the browser, the `replace()` always works for th `@` character, but never for the `+`.

To debug this, I've tried swapping positions of the `.replace('@','_')` with `.replace('+','_')` and even breaking things out like this:

```
var someVar = 'first+last@domain.com';
var cleanVar = someVar.replace('@','_');
var cleanVar2 = cleanVar.replace('+','_');
```

Surely I'm missing something rudimentary here. I know the `+` combines strings in Javascript... but not when surrounded by quotes, right?

Comment: [How is that?](http://jsfiddle.net/737hp127/1/). Both log `first_last_domain.com` in the fiddle. You're logging a wrong variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: you just be doing something wrong. the running code works as expected, just like the console runned code

Comment: Not a dup, OP says that a character is not replaced at all, though it's not reproducable with the provided code.

Comment: the question obviously is not how to replace all occurences in a string, is it? not a dub

Comment: @Alex, It seems like the only way to have this happen-- we're still waiting on feedback.

Comment: Bleh. This is on a Drupal site using JS Injector. All of the JS is being preprocessed and aggregated into a single file. If I turn that off, this problem vanishes. There must be some other script that's interfereing. Keeping preprocessing on and using the regex method below works for now.

Answer (score -1):

This regex method worked for me:

```
var cleanVar = someVar.replace(/[+@]/g,'_');
```

(*posted by someone earlier and then removed*)

As noted by a commenter, this will replace all instances of `@` and `+`. Remove the `g` to target only the first `@` or `+`.

Comment: still is not really an answer to the question